# Update logged in user's signature in Outlook, Office 365 add in through a external rest service?

Tags: outlook, scripting, outlook-web-addins

I have been asked to develop a add in to update user signatures from a external service, that service will be providing the data for the signature and I need to update the signature in outlook with html and data.
Is this possible with some kind of script or any api available in outlook addin to update signatures?
while searching I came across [this](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/34366978-outlook-com-support-to-update-email-signature-vi) it seems there is no api for it at the moment, is it possible with some sort of script?

Answer (score 0):

All Outlook profiles in a Windows user account use the same path for the signature files. If the signatures are in the `Signatures` folder, they are available to all profiles set up in that Windows user account. See [Multiple Profiles and Separate Signature Files](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/multiple-profiles-separate-signatures-files/) for more information.

The default folder where Outlook email signature files are located is:

- Windows XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures
```

- Windows 10 / 8 / 7 / Vista:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

Also, you may find the [How to Find the Outlook 2013 Signature Location](https://www.live2tech.com/find-outlook-2013-signature-location/) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, updating existing signatures in registry from within an Outlook add-in is not supported.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) are considered, when we go through our planning process.